# Would a table lock speed up an update statement in Oracle 10g enterprise?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle10g

We have a fairly wide table BaseData with some 33 millions rows in it. Then we have an update query that joins it to several other tables containing all kinds of parameters, some functions are applied, there is a group by original Id and then the results are written back to the BaseData table in a few columns.

This process is very slow so I'm looking into ways of speeding it up. I have most of my experience in SQLServer so all this type of internals of Oracle I don't know yet.

One thing I suspect is that during the update Oracle creates versions of every row so any oher readers can read that unaffected row. This however takes up considerable resources. Is there any way to have the update take a write lock on the table so it wouldn't create versions of every row?

Any other tips you guys have for large updates? We already broke it down into batches. Each batch is in a seperate partition of the table and then several updates are run in parallel. But still its all much too slow.

Comment: Oracle isn't creating copies of rows, its using undo segments to ensure read consistency.  I'll suggest another approach to doing mass updates soon...

Comment: Can you post an outline of the statement (or the statement itself).

Comment: Hi all, sorry really busy with something else, hopelfully back later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that no, in Oracle, taking an exclusive lock on a table won't prevent other sessions from reading it, or having to incur the work of generating a read-consistent view of the data.  Similarly, in Oracle, you can't tell a session to enable "dirty reads."

Well, the first question is what's slow - is it all the work of joining and applying functions, or is it the writing back?  How does a `SELECT my_updated_resultset FROM BASEDATA JOIN...` perform compared to your update statement?  Have you verified that there's contention between the readers of BaseData and the update process?  Also, it's it too slow for the business, or just slower than you think it should be?

Another option to consider is to use partition exchange to perform your updates.  The high level concept would be:

1. `CREATE TABLE BASEDATA_XCHG as SELECT * FROM BASEDATA WHERE 1 = 0;`
2. `INSERT /*+ append */ INTO BASEDATA_XCHG SELECT my_updated_resultset FROM BASEDATA PARTITION (ONLY_ONE_PARTITION) JOIN...`
3. Create all the required indexes and constraints on the BASEDATA_XCHG table.
4. `ALTER TABLE BASEDATA EXCHANGE PARTITION (ONLY_ONE_PARTITION) WITH BASEDATA_XCHG`

If you're updating most of the rows in a partition of BASEDATA table, don't update them - create a new table and exchange it out.  Tim Gorman has an excellent paper called ["Scaling to Infinity"](http://www.evdbt.com/TGorman%20TD2005%20DWScale.doc) that covers this concept in greater depth; you may wish to check it out.

Comment: Hi, thx. We looked into that, the selects are much faster than the updates, that's why I was looking there. Also the throughput seems to grow exponentially with the number of rows in the batch. We're redeviding the work into smaller batches. It's too slow for business so we really need to speed this up. Else it looks we'll have to scrap this and go with c++ or somehting for the calc stuff. I'll look into the partition swapping. Other idea was to not update but insert into another table that we can then join to the original.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Adam's answer:

Run an EXPLAIN PLAN on your update statement and check the execution plan.

Chances are that adding indexes to support your joins and WHERE conditions can speed up the query.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses undo segments for read consistency (along with SCNs, read more [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#i5702))

I'm assuming these large batch processes are running on a staging area and not a "prod" instance that is being used by a lot of various processes.  If you are updating 25% or more (rough figures) of some big table, it may be better to do a CTAS (create table as select...) than attempting updates.  Your CTAS would contain the update logic for the new table.  Once done, add indexes/grants/etc on new table and rename new to old.  You can also add a parallel hint and nologging on the CTAS to potentially speed things up even more.

Comment: If you are updating a table you are querying from, as well as generating the UNDO it also has to apply the undo so it can see the table as it was at the start of the statement.